# Every time I tap using UITapGestureRecognizer memory usage increase. why?

Tags: memory, profiler, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'have just create a "Single View Application" with xcode and I add a UITapGestureRecognizer
in "viewDidLoad" method.
Then I monitor memory allocation whith instruments and every time I tap the size of the allocated memory increase.  If try to tap several time the memory usage increase.
why this behaviour?

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)handleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
   // NSLog(@"....");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this, but I think it is because the system's memory is dynamically allocated, so when it realizes it needs more to handle the button action, it will use more memory

Comment: Ok, but If I tap 100 times..the memory increase proportionally. There is the possibility to face to “unbounded memory growth” problem?

Comment: And it doesn't go down if you wait a couple of minutes?